# Onclick event handler by window.onload doesn't trigger

Tags: mouseevent

I want to call the function "details" when an element with the class "link" is clicked. This code doesn't work:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("link").onclick = details;
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("link")` will select an element with an `id` of "link", not an element with a `class` of "link".

Depending on what browsers you need to support, you might use `document.getElementsByClassName()` instead. (Won't work in IE8 or below, but [works in all other browsers you are likely to care about](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname).) You'll have to assign the click handler to each element that is returned.

Comment: Hi Trott, it doesn't work either. I've tried this:     document.getElementsByClassName("link").onclick = mostra_detalls;

Comment: You can't just replace `getElementById()` in your code with `getElementsByClassName()` and expect it to work. You will have to assign the click handler to each element that is returned. For example, you might choose to loop through the results.